# Observable with Timer for specifc value

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Not sure about the title of my question but hopefully I can explain what I am trying to do.

I want to have a Timer to inject a value into a sequence but when a specific value is observed.
I want the Timer to be cancelled when any other value is entered into the sequence.

```
public enum State
{
    Connected,
    Disconnected,
    DisconnectedRetryTimeout
}

var stateSubject = new Subject<State>();

var connectionStream = stateSubject.AsObservable();

var disconnectTimer = 
    Observable.Return(State.DisconnectedRetryTimeout)
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        .Concat(Observable.Never<State>());

var disconnectSignal =
    disconnectedTimer
        .TakeUntil(connectionStream.Where(s => s == State.Connected))
        .Repeat();

var statusObservable = 
    Observable.Merge(connectionStream, disconnectSignal)
        .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

So when nothing is in the stream (i.e. new) no timer.
When Connected|DisconnectedRetryTimeout is add no timer.
When Disconnected is add I want the timer to start
If Connected is on the stream before the timer fires I want the timer cancelled
The Timer should  only fire once, until Disconnected is received again.

Pretty new to RX and ran out of ideas on this one.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly: We start with a state stream that will emit either `Connected` or `Disconnected` messages. We want to enrich this with `DisconnectedRetryTimeout` message that appears if a `Disconnected` message sits on the stream for 30 seconds without a `Connected` message appearing.

One way to do this has the following idea:

Project the Connected/Disconnected stream into the DisconnectedRetryTimeout stream as follows:

- First strip duplicates with `DistinctUntilChanged` as we only want the first `Disconnected` message of a batch to start a timer.
- If Disconnected is received, project this event as a stream that emits `DisconnectedRetryTimeout` after 30 seconds
- If Connected is received, just project an infinite and empty stream (`Observable.Never`)
- With the above, we end up with a stream of streams, so now we use `Switch` which flattens this by always taking the most recent stream. So if `Connect` appears whilst the timer is in flight, the `Never` stream will replace the timer stream.

Now we can merge this with the original de-duped stream. Note that we publish the de-duped stream because we will be subscribing to it twice - if we don't do this, and the source is cold then we can run into problems. See more about that [here](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=144).

```
var stateSubject = new Subject<State>();

var state = stateSubject.DistinctUntilChanged().Publish().RefCount();

var disconnectTimer = state        
    .Select(x => x == State.Disconnected
        ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
            .Select(_ => State.DisconnectedRetryTimeout)
        : Observable.Never<State>())
    .Switch();

var statusObservable =
    state.Merge(disconnectTimer);
```

#### EDIT: Simpler Version

You can do this all in one go and drop the publish step and merge - by using `StartWith` we can push the `Disconnected` events through the timer stream, and with `Observable.Return` we can push the `Connected` through replacing the empty `Never` stream:

```
var statusObservable = stateSubject
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Select(x => x == State.Disconnected
        ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                    .Select(_ => State.DisconnectedRetryTimeout)
                    .StartWith(State.Disconnected)
        : Observable.Return(State.Connected))
    .Switch();
```

Comment: @antinutrino - good stuff - I found a lighter weight solution now too and edited it in.